# cocos2d(x), execute something on next frame?

Tags: menu, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

For example, I'm adding a menu and want to set it's priority.

setHandlerPriority checks if the menu is associated with a touch handler and it fails because addition is scheduled on next loop(pushed onto a queue).

How can I add a menu(as a child) and set its priority at the same time?
Or how can I call the 'setHandlerPriority' on next loop?

Does 'runAction' with 'CCCallFunc' execute the function on next frame?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can create a sequence of actions.

those actions can be a CCDelayTime or CCCallFunc, then they can be called with the order you want it to be. just use any CCNode to run that action.